# Is Github libraries can be editable?

Tags: android, git, github, jitsi

I've add a github library and have a kind of error so i want to make changes on some classes but file is only read. How can I edit this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot edit this class because its a decompiled class. When you clicked and opened the class, Android studio decompiled the .jar or .dex file on-the-fly to show you that class. You can edit only .java or .kt files. Not the decompiled .class file.

If you want to make some changes to the Jitsi Meet library you have two options -

- Fork the repo -> Make change -> Create pull request -> Wait for it to be merged and use the new version.

Or

- Import the whole library locally into your project as a new module -> Remove Jitsi library remote dependency -> Add dependency for local Jitsi library module -> Make whatever changes you want in the source code java/kotlin files.

Comment: As far as i get you mean; In Github Clone or Download -> Download Zip then In Android Studio -> File ->New->import project then go build gradle app -> dependencies: remove current lib and add forked module source ?

Comment: but the module name is not appear

Comment: did you add the module to your settings.gradle file?

Comment: rootProject.name='jitsimeet'
include ':app', ':sdk'  

these are automatically added

Comment: in this link step 6 is not same as mine stackoverflow.com/a/32600942/3090120 module name is not appear

Comment: Oh that, you can ignore that. Module name is not imp.

Comment: Files are not appear also :(

Comment: Okay, so do this. Clone the repo to your system, copy the sdk folder to your project folder beside the app folder. Put `include ':app', ':sdk'` in settings.gradle and finally `implementation project(':androidlibrarymaster');`. This should work. Although you shouldnt need to be doing this since you shouldnt need to change the files of a library. This might not work since the Jitsi meet library seems to be dependent on other scripts and files as well.